# Getting error 1336 duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64

Tags: swift, realm

after adding SwipeCellKit pod on my project, i am now getting this error in the title.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u9d8p.png)

Trying to search this on stack over flow but most of dudes there are talking about react native.

For more default checks in found on Build Phases, there are no duplicated files too:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XPDsS.png)

Podfile:

```
platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'Todoey' do

use_frameworks!  

# Pods for Todoey  

pod 'RealmSwift' 

pod 'SwipeCellKit'  

end
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33125781/duplicate-symbols-when-adding-realm-cocoapod

Comment: Did you use Cocoapods? If yes, can you share the content of your podfile?

Comment: @rs7
`platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'Todoey' do
  
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for Todoey

pod 'RealmSwift'
pod 'SwipeCellKit'

end`

Comment: @matt so basically i need to adapt my xcode version to the one supported by realm?
But isnt strange code was running normally then i installed another pod then started to crash?

Comment: Please don't put code in comments, add them to the question so they are searchable and also formatted for readability. No, you do not need to 'adapt' your XCode - however we don't know which XCode version you're running. It appears cocoapods may need to be updated and building for iOS9 is a little old. You may want to update your cocoapods and podfile and try again.

Comment: @Jay, Xcode version: 11.5.
Ok, i will update cocoapods and the podfile, will let you know

Comment: I think i resolved my problem. Based on @matt answer, i deleted my Pods folder then made another pod install, using same xcode version either on podfile, same realm version. Without SwipeCellKit implementation on code is not presenting problems anymore. I really dont know how issue started, but i guess it is working fine now.

Comment: Excellent, thanks for reporting back. You can answer your own question (totally legal), or just delete the question.

Answer (score 0):

Based on post that @matt shared ([Duplicate Symbols when adding Realm Cocoapod](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33125781/duplicate-symbols-when-adding-realm-cocoapod?noredirect=1&lq=1))

I deleted my Pods folder then made another pod install, using same xcode version either on podfile, same realm version. Without SwipeCellKit implementation on code is not presenting problems anymore.